# Would backpropagation work as expect when using this code as swish in a CNN?

Tags: python, pytorch, activation-function

I would like to use swish (as a layer) in a CNN.

I am not sure if this is the correct way to implement a such activation function.

Will back propagation work properly with this code?

```
class Swish(nn.Module):
    def forward(self,x):
        return x * F.sigmoid(x)
```

The relevant information on what programming language I am using can be found in the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work out of the box.

I don't see why you would make it an object though, function like this would be easier and more readable IMO (and it would reflect it's functional nature better):

```
def swish(x):
    return x * torch.nn.functional.sigmoid(x)
```

You don't need `torch.nn.Module` if you are not using any `parameters` (like learnable `torch.nn.Linear` weights, CNNs or others).